# Bootstrap-datepicker not POSTing hidden values correctly

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using bootstrap-datepicker and need to send both the date selected and a hidden value when user hits the submit button.  Code is so:

```
            <div class='input-append date datepicker' data-date=$today data-date-format='mm-dd-yyyy'>
            <form class='well' action='Update_Birthday.php' method='POST'>  
            <input type='hidden' name='ContactID' value=$ContactID>
            <input class='span5' size='16' type='text' name='date' readonly>
            <span class='add-on'><i class='icon-calendar'></i></span>
            <button type='submit' class='btn'>Submit</button>  
            </form> 
        </div>
```

If I click Submit before selecting a date, then ContactID is sent correctly (but date is null of course).  When I select a date, then both 'ContactID' and 'date' are identical, i.e. the date selected by the user.

How do I send the date AND hidden values correctly?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With this code (essentially what you have already, with quotes added to values):

```
        <div class='input-append date datepicker' data-date='$today' data-date-format='mm-dd-yyyy'>
        <form class='well' id='birthdayForm' action='Update_Birthday.php' method='POST'>  
        <input type='hidden' name='ContactID' value='$ContactID'>
        <input class='span5 dateInput' size='16' type='text' name='date' readonly>
        <span class='add-on'><i class='icon-calendar'></i></span>
        <button type='submit' class='btn'>Submit</button>  
        </form> 
    </div>
```

There's no reason `ContactID` should be overwritten when a user selects a date.

As for preventing form submission until a date is selected, that will require some JavaScript. I would suggest just prefilling the `date` input with a value (possibly the previously specified birthday, judging by your code?) - since the field is readonly, users will generally be unable to empty the value, only change the date.

If you prefer to leave it blank, something like this should help:

```
$('#birthdayForm').on('submit', function(e) {
    $('.dateInput').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val().length < 1) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Sara.  I notice you use id=, but I have several of these datepickers on screen.  As such I reference them with class=datepicker above.  Could this be the issue? (BTW  I'm not concerned with validation as datepicker caters for this).

Comment: The date ID was just for the jQuery example, it's not related to your `ContactID` problem. I've updated my answer to use a class instead.